# pthread_create error

Tags: c

I have

```
    client_sock = accept(server_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_name, &client_name_len);        
    if (pthread_create(&newthread , NULL, (void * ) accept_request, client_sock) != 0) {
            perror("pthread_create");
    }
```

That's just part of the entire script. Every time I try to compile it, I get `warning: passing argument 4 of 'pthread_create' makes pointer from integer without a cast`

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Argument 4 is `client_sock`, which is the argument that gets passed to `accept_request`. It is expected to be a pointer, but since it's just passed through to your function, it can be an integer without doing any harm. Just cast it to `void*` to remove the warning.

On the other hand, the third argument `accept_request` should be a function pointer accepting `void*` and returning `void*`. You shouldn't have to cast it to `void*`. It would be best to change the declaration of `accept_request` to match the specification.

```
void *accept_request( void *client_sock );
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume client_sock is defined as "int client_sock". In this case you should write the following:

```
if (pthread_create(&newthread , NULL, (void * ) accept_request, &client_sock) != 0) {
```

Then in accept_request (which, btw, should be a function taking a pointer) you will do like:

```
void *accept_request( void *client_sock_addr ) {
   int client_sock = *((int*) client_sock_addr);
}
```

Converting an int to an (void*) might not be portable (as data sizes of int and void* are not necessarily the same). Of course, it might work on your current compiler...

Thanks jiles for pointing this: Depending on the rest of the code, the value at that address might change (for example if you have a loop around the accept construct and 2 accepts arrive before one thread is created). The nicest way to do it is indeed allocate memory with malloc like

```
int *client_sock_addr=malloc(sizeof(int)); 
*client_sock_addr = accept(server_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_name, &client_name_len);        
if (pthread_create(&newthread , NULL, (void * ) accept_request, client_sock_addr) != 0) {
        perror("pthread_create");
}
```

And then in the function do:

```
void *accept_request( void *param ) {
   int *client_sock_addr = (int*) client_sock_addr;
   int client_sock = *client_sock_addr;

   // Before exiting the thread
   free(client_sock_addr);
}
```

Comment: int client_sock = -1;
I'm not sure why, but when I put &client_sock instead of client_sock, the entire socket stops working. Any ideas?

Comment: This change introduces a new problem. There is nothing that ensures that the pointer and the data it points to remain valid until the thread is done with it. Some ways to fix this: malloc the parameter block and free it in the thread, have the thread signal that it is done with the parameter and wait for that before invalidating it.

Comment: Usually it is best to group the parameters to the thread in a `struct` with the `pthread_t` object. When you join with the thread, you can dispose of the `struct` or reuse it or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because you are not respecting the signature of `pthread_create`:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict thread,
              const pthread_attr_t *restrict attr,
              void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *restrict arg);
```

As you can see the third argument should be a function pointer so the correct cast would be to `(void *(*)(void*))` and for `client_sock` which will be the argument to `start_routine` you have to take the address like that `&client_sock`